MYSQL Return all rows with additional column for max value for the set without grouping
I know it is weird to try and get the MAX value without a GROUP BY, but maybe there is a way to do what I need.
Lets say I have the following table...



UserID
UserName
UserScore




1
John
35


2
Steve
20


3
Chris
40


4
Paul
65


5
Frank
45



What I need to be able to do is return all rows where the score is > 30, but I also need to know what the max value is in that result set. My actual WHERE clause is a bit complicated, so I need to avoid duplicating the WHERE part, or querying the data twice to get the answer.
My ideal scenario/pseudo query...
SELECT UserID, UserName, UserScore, GROUP_MAX(UserScore) AS ScoreMax FROM Users
WHERE UserScore > 30
ORDER BY UserScore;

Result set would look like this...



UserID
UserName
UserScore
ScoreMax




1
John
35
65


3
Chris
40
65


5
Frank
45
65


4
Paul
65
65



Then at any point I can reference ScoreMax at the row level.
Tried subqueries and UNION but both proved to be too slow for our large dataset.

Use ,
SELECT UserID,
       UserName,
       UserScore,
       MAX(UserScore) OVER () AS ScoreMax
FROM Users
WHERE UserScore > 30 
ORDER BY UserScore

See example

I recommend reading Window Function Concepts and Syntax

Interesting (but good) behavior. If I include a LIMIT clause, this includes the MAX value of rows not included in the LIMITed result. Not what I expected, but actually what I need. PERFECT!
Let me know if I am misunderstanding the behavior.

@ihatzi - that is expected/correct behavior.  Limit only affects what is returned to the client after everything else has been done.
